# Get content from yaml file

Tags: ruby

I want to get the content from YALM file `qqpay, online_banking, bank_payout` using Ruby. I tried this:

YAML File content:

```
paysec:
  supported_trx_types: [qqpay, online_banking, bank_payout]
```

Ruby code:

```
def load_paysec_payment_type_with_base_params
    YAML.load_file("config/gateway_supported_trx_types.yml")['paysec']['supported_trx_types']
    raise "\n\nMissing configuration for paysec in file config/gateway_supported_trx_types.yaml}"
  end
```

Iterate into the file content:

```
load_paysec_payment_type_with_base_params.each do |factory_name|
      process_trx([factory_name.to_s], GATEWAY_NAME, base_params_for(factory_name))
    end
```

But I get exception:

```
sanity_checks.rb:32:in `execute':  (RuntimeError)

Missing configuration for paysec in file config/gateway_supported_trx_types.yaml}
```

What is the proper way to get the content?

Comment: your raise an error always, you need to do that only when you effectively run into a problem, comment out the raise and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this:

```
def load_paysec_payment_type_with_base_params
   begin
      YAML.load_file("config/gateway_supported_trx_types.yml")['paysec']['supported_trx_types']
   rescue Exception => e  
      "\n\nMissing configuration for paysec in file config/gateway_supported_trx_types.yaml}. reason: " + e.message
end
```